# Add and Delete Operation on HTML Object Clone

Tags: jquery

i have a select like this, for which i created clone , now i want to add and remove option by value in clonecity object, please help

```js
var $city = $('select[name=city]');
var $clonecity = $city.find('option').clone();
```

```html
<select name="city" id="city">
    <option stateid="1" value="1"> City1 </option>
    <option stateid="1" value="2"> city2 </option>
    <option stateid="2" value="3"> city3 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can use any of the standard jquery methods on the cloned element, ie `append()` and `remove()`

Comment: what do you mean with "option by value"?

Comment: i want to add new element like <option stateid="2" value="4"> city4 </option> or delete one which value is 2 by jquery